# pymongo using find() to query an array always fails

Tags: python, arrays, mongodb-query, find, pymongo

I've been searching this for about half the evening and I cannot seem to understand or find my error.

I am attempting to connect to a MongoDB and search a table for a specific string. I do not care what field the string is in, only that if either field in the row contains the string it should return the contents of the 'name' field.

I've tried a bunch of different ways of writing this, and I always seem to come up with something along the lines of:

```
search_for_mapname(mpname):

    # create the MongoDB client and connect to the database
    dbclient = pymongo.MongoClient(dbtoken)

    # check for mpname
    cursor = dbclient.database.maps.find( { 'name': mpname, "$or":[{"aliases":mpname}] } )
    for map in cursor:
        return map['name']
    return "INVALID"
```

Each row is structured like this:

```
{ 'name': "ff_2fort", 'aliases': ["2fort", "2", "alias"] }
```

`find()` seems to recognize when `mpname == maps['name']` but when I input an alias that I know exists, I get "INVALID" every time.

Answer (score 0):

I found my mistake, $or does not work like I have it written above, it should actually be written like this:

```
cursor = dbclient.FortressForever.maps.find( { "$or":[ {"name": mpname}, {"aliases":mpname}] } )
```